# datastax cassandra driver: how to return success or failure from list of ResultSet for insert statements

Tags: cassandra, kotlin, datastax, future, objectmapper

I'm using the [datastax object mapper](https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/2.1/manual/object_mapper/using/) and [accessor](https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/2.1/manual/object_mapper/using/#return-type) to insert data into my cassandra tables. In the documentation linked, it says that the return type specification affects how the query gets executed. I want the query to execute asynchronously, so I choose to use `ResultSetFuture`:

```
@Accessor
interface MyTableAccessor {
    @Query("INSERT INOT MY_TABLE " +
        "SET value = :v " +
        "WHERE $ID = :id ")
    fun insertValue(@Param("v") value: String, @Param("id") id: String): ResultSetFuture
}
```

My insert call is:

```
val id = ...
val insertFutures = myList.map {
  myTableAccessor.insertValue(it, id)
}
```

I also have added a callback for these futures:

```
insertFutures.forEach {
    Futures.addCallback(it, MyCallback(stats, tags))
}
```

where `MyCallback` implements the `FutureCallback` interface. I finish the call with:

```
return Futures.inCompletionOrder(insertFutures)
    .map { it.get() }
```

This returns to me a `List<ResultSet>`.
But I want to return a `Boolean` for the insert call to indicate that the insert operation succeeded. I'm not sure how I can do that with the returned `List<ResultSet>`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

insert queries return result only if the lightweight transactions (LWTs) are used. In other cases, insert queries don't return anything, and the success of operation is that fact that you got `ResultSet` instead of exception. So in your case, you just add the `onSuccess` callback that always returns true, and `onFailure` that returns false.